# Retornar uma função a ser executada - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, express.js, promises, async-await

Estou com uma situação, onde eu gostaria de gerar um motor que execute uma função async e que execute um callback de sucesso no try e um de erro no catch, sendo que a responsabilidade desses callbacks seja mandar um res.send() no Express.

**Código motor:**

```
public async runAsyncFunction(asyncFunction: Promise<any>, 
   errorCallback: () => Response, 
   successCallback?: (any) => Response) {

    try {

        const data = await asyncFunction;

        if (!successCallback) {
            return data;
        }

        return successCallback(data);

    } catch (error) {
        return errorCallback();
    }
}
```

**Código funções de Callback**

```
export class ResponseHandler {

public successResponse(responseModel: any, res: Response) {
    return () => res.status(statusCode.success_ok).send(responseModel);
}

public unauthorizedResponse(res: Response, responseModel: ResponseModel, errorMessage: string) {

    responseModel.message = errorMessage;

    return () => res.status(statusCode.client_error_unauthorized).send(responseModel);
}
```

}

**Invocação na controller**

```
const userInfoResponse = await this.asyncHandler.runAsyncFunction(this.idmService.getToken(access_token),
        this.responseHandler.unauthorizedResponse(res, modelResposta,
            'mensagem de erro'));
```

O erro que estou recebendo é o seguinte:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Valeu!!

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o padrao `.then()` `.catch()` das promises
Encapsula a promise que vem no parametro e retorna uma nova promisse, ai nem precisa dos callbacks. Esta um pouco confuso esses trechos de codigo mas acredito que seja mais ou menos isso.

```
export class ResponseHandler {

    public successResponse(responseModel: any, res: Response) {
        return res.status(statusCode.success_ok).send(responseModel);
    }

    public unauthorizedResponse(res: Response, responseModel: ResponseModel, errorMessage: string) {

        responseModel.message = errorMessage;

        return res.status(statusCode.client_error_unauthorized).send(responseModel);
    }
}
```

```
public async runAsyncFunction(asyncFunction: Promise<any>) {
    const pr = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        try {
            const data = await asyncFunction;
            resolve(data)
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
    })

    return pr
}
```

Ai no seu controller faz algo assim

```
const userInfoResponse = await this.asyncHandler.runAsyncFunction(this.idmService.getToken(access_token))
            .then(data=>console.log('sucesso'))
            .catch(erro=>this.responseHandler.unauthorizedResponse(res, modelResposta,'mensagem de erro'))
```